# How to implement Navigation Drawer with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to follow the latest Google's good practises implementing a single Activity Application with Navigation Components.

However after reading the whole Navigation documentation I still think there are a lot of cases that they don't address.

For example, How should I implement the following case:

[image: navgraph]

- App starts in a splash screen. Then after some loading goes to the News Fragment.

**Note:** Splash Screen should pop from the backstack, since it shouldn't be acessible anymore.

- A Navigation Drawer should be available in all fragments of Section 1, allowing the user to navigate between fragments in this section.
- However some fragments in the section can navigate to a new area which should have a back button (not a drawer).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a new project with selected `Navigation Drawer Activity`?

**1. Drawer**

In XML you should add for this activity a `FrameLayout` that will hold fragments. Then you can start using this activity as a container for your fragments and on `DrawerMenuItem` click, you load a particular fragment.
I use this method to reload fragments:

```
public void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment, Bundle args){
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}
```

and call it like this from activity:

```
replaceFragment(Fragment.newInstance(), args)
```

Then you have your drawer available in all fragments.

**2. Details screen with back arrow**

As for another screen with for example Article details, you could start activity with details:

`startActivity(new Intent(packageContext, ArticleDetailsActivity.class));`

Then there is no drawer and you have a back button.

**3. Splash**

As for creating a "good" splash screen Google "Android splash screen the right way", there are posts on medium (by Sylvain Saurel) or bignerdranch (by Chris Stewart) that cover this topic.

Comment: This is what I have at the moment. However, this is not using Android Navigation Component.

Comment: Oh, right. I don't know why I didn't notice that tag :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `DestinatedChangedListener` on the `nav controller` to `lock` and `unlock` the drawer mode.